# Get current page number in axAcroPDF1

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf

Hello I've been trying to get the pagenumber of the page currently displayed in the viewer axAcroPDF.
There is a post on this forum with the same question but this seems to be VB code.

I hope someone can help me:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.AddExtension = true;
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF Files | *.pdf";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Kies een bestand";

            try
            {
                openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }


        axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
        axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filename);
        axAcroPDF1.setShowScrollbars(false);
        axAcroPDF1.Show();


   }
```

Comment: I removed the tag iTextSharp as I don't see any code that refers to iText or iTextSharp

Comment: I use PdfReader to read the pdf's. In the code sample this isn't shown indeed. I thought maybe this could be used to get the current page number.

Comment: What do you mean by "current page number"? `PdfReader` is a class file that can inspect a PDF, but there's no such thing as a current page number in `PdfReader`. Why would there be? Are you saying there's a product named axAcroPDF1 that uses iText to render PDFs?

Comment: I mean the current page number showing in the axAcroPDF1 pdf viewer.

Comment: The itext library isn't used here. I use that in a other part to extract the pages.

Comment: Well, if iTextSharp isn't used, I was right to remove the tag. I have no idea why you thought an external library could be used to know the current page number shown in a viewer that isn't connected to iTextSharp in any way.